# ASP.NET - Getting source code of a website - Connection attempt fails

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to get the source code of another website on my asp.net website. Whenever I run the project (debug it on my local machine) this code works absolutely fine.
Default aspx scource code:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="url_show" runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button" runat="server" OnClick="calc"/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="source_show" runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox>
```

and the default.aspx.cs source code :

```
    protected void calc(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string address = url_show.Text;
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            string content = wc.DownloadString(address);
            source_show.Text = content;
        }
    }
```

However when I run it on the server (http://www.1und1.de) I get the following error messsage:

- A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 173.194.35.152:80
- Source Error: An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

  Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: You can't connect and you often can't obtain the source code.

Comment: Are you triyng to get html code of a web page?

Comment: yes and it works just fine, for example with url = http://www.google.com when I run it in debug  mode on localhost.

Comment: Turn off the firewall on the server. Can you open google.com from your browser?

Comment: 173.194.35.152:80 does not correspond to http://www.1und1.de - could be a DNS issue - more likely a firewall issue as mentioned above